# Git Issue with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, git-for-windows

Recently when Git 2.30.1 installed on my machine , I start getting various error in VS 2019.

Common issues

- Authentication issue.
- ExecuteFetch
- Pull operation failed.

Environment

- VS 2019 Professional
- Git 2.30.1

Is there any solution for this ?

Is there any way I can completely remove git from machine and install it again.

Comment: Have you tried other means of using Git for your repository (command line, some other GUI tool, etc.) and do you experience the same issues?

Comment: It is working from Git-bash. For this too it ask credential and when we supply username and personal access token it is working. It is not reading from Credential manager. 
1. I did uninstall Git for Windows from Visual Studio component.
2. Removed git from control panel add remove program and deleted git directory from visual studio extention and program files
3. Install Git for windows from VS 2019 
Same issues : Specially I am getting terminal prompt disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check first in command-line:

- if you can fetch/pull the same repository
- the type of URL used for your remote origin (HTTPS or SSH)

If it is HTTPS, check your `git config credential.helper`: if it is `manager-core`, then [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core` issue 245](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/245) might be the issue.

For testing, try and switch to an SSH URL and see if the repository works better with VS 2019.